# facebox opened page get querystring

Tags: asp.net, html, query-string, facebox

Im in a page mainpage.aspx" in which i have this code:
`<a rel="facebox" href="destination.htm?path=blabla">mainpage</a>`
Im using facebox() to load the destination.htm
The problem is in my destination.htm,when im trying to hit an alert(window.location.href) im getting the mainpage.aspx  and not the destination.htm.why ? all i want to do is to read the path from the page to get the querystring (but im getting the wrong path).

thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because facebox is not actually redirecting the browser to that page, but fetching via ajax and injecting it into the facebox div on the same page.

You could try grabbing the href attribute of the anchor instead, perhaps something like:

```
var lastVisited = null;
var lastVisitedQS = null;
$("a[rel='facebox']").facebox()
          .click(function() {
              lastVisited = this.href;

              // you can extract the query string like this
              var a = document.createElement('a');
              a.href = lastVisited;
              lastVisitedQS = a.search; // should give path=blabla
          });
```

and then in your `destination.htm` do:

```
alert(lastVisited);
alert(lastVisitedQS);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Grace - oops, there was a mistake in the code (I forgot to declare `a`)

Comment: just one thing : the line var lastVisited = null; must be taken out, or else it wont work. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.hostname to get host URL, window.location.pathname to get virtual dir+page and window.location.search to get querystring part of URL